# Not able to load universal-sentence-encoder-large/3 on MAC from local cache

Tags: macos, python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

While running the below programme to load universal-sentence-encoder-large/3
getting the below error

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
m = hub.Module("tensorflow_objects/USEL3")
```

Below is the error log

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using /var/folders/lb/qcf6q0rd29g422mh1gst4k2r0000gn/T/tfhub_modules to cache modules.
INFO:tensorflow:Op RegexReplace is missing from both the python and C++ registry.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py", line 126, in __init__
    tags=self._tags)
  File "pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py", line 282, in _create_impl
    name=name)
  File "pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py", line 325, in __init__
    op.name for op in self._meta_graph.meta_info_def.stripped_op_list.op})
  File "pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py", line 712, in register_ops_if_needed
    % missing_ops.difference(set(cpp_registry_ops.keys())))
RuntimeError: Graph ops missing from the python registry (set([u'RegexReplace'])) are also absent from the c++ registry
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably means you are running in an older tensorflow version.

- RegexReplace was added in [tensorflow-1.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.7.0).

Comment: @ André Susano Pinto thank you for the answer, I was using tensorflow 1.6, upgraded it to 1.8 and it worked